# Second monitor showing black

Tags: windows-7, display

I have a strange situation atm I have a client using a DisplayLink USB GD adaptor with a AOC Monitor running Win 7 on a HP 250 G1 Notebook.

The issue is that when they plugin and go to use the monitor its black and you cannot see nothing - However when I access via Teamviewer its working fine and I can swap screens.

How can this be fixed so they can see the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the right river for the display link unit.

I've been using one for a while at work and we had a very similar issue.
Turned out that a lower spec usb adapter was ordered and didn't realize until we checked out the model number.
The lower spec model basically showed nothing if the PC was trying a resolution higher than what it was capable of.
The docs were poor

Comment: Was a dodgy driver for vid card + upgraded the DL drivers and it worked

Answer (score 1):

1. Try a new video cable to ensure it's not faulty.
2. Try the monitor on another machine to ensure the monitor isn't faulty.
3. Try a known-good monitor with the problematic display adapter to ensure it's not faulty.
4. Replace whichever part you discover is faulty.